# Cancelling out of WiX Bundle exe Displays Previous Setup UI

Tags: wix

I'm new to WiX and inherited several WiX projects from a previous employee.  There is a 'Full' installer that bundles several .msi packages for installation.  The Full installer consists of a project with a Bundle.wxs file and another project with a .xaml UI screen and a bootstrapper class.  The UI simply lets the user performing the install choose which components to install.

I'm seeing a really odd issue where if I kick off one of the components and then cancel out of the .msi installation process for that component previous versions of the .xaml UI screen display.  I end up having to close out several of these UI screens before I get back to the one I kicked off for my install.  The behavior differs on our different test servers and it seems like there are old installers cached on the servers or something.  The .xaml UI screens that pop up after trying to cancel include fields that are not part of my current .xaml UI.

Comment: Yes, there is caching. The WiX bootstrapper (project with a bundle), is a package manager. I can't explain much of the behavior you are seeing but be sure to increment the bundle version for builds that are promoted to test.

Comment: Thanks, versioning the bundle does not resolve my issue but I will update the version going forward.  I saw quite a few entries in the registry for the full installer and I don't think there should be any.  The full installer is just supposed to be an executable that lets the user choose which .msi files to kick off and there really shouldn't be any registry entries around it.  The full installer is not available to uninstall from add\remove programs, just the separate programs installed by the selected .msi files are.  It's almost like the full installer is getting installed in some manner.

Comment: The WiX boostrapper engine, "burn," is a _package manager,_ not just a bundler/chainer/downloader/reboot manager/bootstrapper. It is installed and uninstalled as a thing itself (regardless if it is showing in Programs and Features [See [DisableRemove](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/bundle.html)]).